# application didReceiveRemoteNotification not called in particular occasion

Tags: objective-c, firebase, push-notification

I am writing an app which will receive remote notifications sent from Firebase.

It works perfectly fine when I first install the app on an iPhone, the notification can be received no matter the app is in background or foreground.

However, when I killed the app and **restarted** it, then press home button again to send it to background, the app can no longer receive notifications in background state, and can only receive on foreground.

Please help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take a look at your app's entitlements. Maybe it's missing Background Modes.

Comment: I already have the key "APS Environment" and value "development" in my app's entitlement. Is this what you mean?